# Mock distribution using dependency injection in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, dependency-injection, scalatest

I’m writing a distributed application in which i want to unit test the application logic separately from the distribution aspect. I have a class `Number` whose `printIP` method depends on a global variable that is the machine's ip address: `Config.ip`.

```
object Config {
    val ip = "192.168.0.0"
}

case class Number(value: Int) {
    def increment = Number(value + 1)
    def printIP = println(Config.ip)
}
```

In production, different instances of `Number` reside on different machines and thus have different ip addresses.
When testing the application logic i want to mimic different IPs:

```
class LogicTest extends FlatSpec {
    val instance1 = Number(1)
    instance1.printIP // prints "192.168.0.0"
    val instance2 = Number(2)
    instance2.printIP // also prints "192.168.0.0"
}
```

Naturally, both instances print the same ip address when tested on one machine. How can i test my application logic locally while mimicking different ip addresses for those instances.

I don’t want to pass the ip address as a class argument to `Number` because this would change the interface of `Number`.

I tried to add a `getIp` method to `Number` which I can override in my unit tests:

```
case class Number(value: Int) {
    def increment = Number(value + 1)
    def getIp = Config.ip
    def printIP = println(getIp)
}

class LogicTest extends FlatSpec {
    val instance1 = new Number(1) { override def getIp = "192.168.0.1" }
    instance1.printIP // prints "192.168.0.1"
    val instance2 = new Number(2) { override def getIp = "192.168.0.2" }
    instance2.printIP // prints "192.168.0.2"
}
```

At first, this seems to work.
However, when i `increment` an instance, it returns a new one and i lose the overridden `getIp` method:

```
class LogicTest extends FlatSpec {
    var instance1 = new Number(1) { override def getIp = "192.168.0.1" }
    instance1.printIP // prints "192.168.0.1" (OK)

    val instance2 = new Number(2) { override def getIp = "192.168.0.2" }
    instance2.printIP // prints "192.168.0.2" (OK)

    val instance3 = instance1.increment
    instance3.printIP // prints "192.168.0.0" (NOT OK)

    val instance4 = instance2.increment
    instance4.printIP // prints “192.168.0.0” (NOT OK)
}
```

I also had a look at the Cake pattern for dependency injection in Scala (http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/), but I fail to see how it can be applied to my case.

---

Update @Dima: It does change the appearance of the interface when replicated objects are nested. Assume the following artificial example:

```
trait Config { def ip: String }
object Config extends Config { val ip = "127.0.0.1" }

case class Number(value: Int)(implicit config: Config = Config) {
   def getIp = config.ip
}

case class NestedNumber(value: Int)(nestedNum: Number = Number(value))
NestedNumber(5)
```

The programmer can create a `NestedNumber` by providing an integer and the class will automatically create a nested number with that value. Again, we now want to inject our configuration object such that we can unit test the application logic separately from the distribution aspect.

```
case class NestedNumber(value: Int)(config: Config = config)(nestedNum: Number = Number(value)(config))
NestedNumber(5)()()
```

The problem is that we need to pass the `config` object when creating `nestedNum`. Hence, we need multiple argument lists. Now, all of a sudden the programmer needs to specify 3 argument lists two of which are empty, instead of just a single argument.

---

Update 2 @Dima: It is common to nest replicated data types inside other replicated data types. For instance, in the literature on CRDTs a Positive-Negative Counter consists of two Grow-only Counters. So this is what I'm actually doing:

```
type IP = String
case class GCounter(val increments: Map[IP, Int] = Map())(implicit val config: Config) {
    val ownIP: IP = config.ip // will be used to increment our entry in the map
}

case class PNCounter(p: GCounter = GCounter(), n: GCounter = GCounter())(implicit config: Config) {
    val ownIP: IP = config.ip
}
```

So now we can make a `PNCounter`:

```
trait Config { def ip: IP }
implicit object Config extends Config { val ip = "192.168.0.1" }

// In production
val pn = PNCounter()
pn.ownIP   // "192.168.0.1" (OK)
pn.p.ownIP // "192.168.0.1" (OK)

// Now suppose we send the replica to a remote actor with IP address "192.168.0.9"
case class ReceiveCounter(replica: PNCounter)
remoteActor ! ReceiveCounter(pn) // message send in Akka

// On the receiver's side
receivedMsg.replica.ownIP // "192.168.0.1" (NOT OK, should be 192.168.0.9)

// When testing on one machine
object TestConfig extends Config { val ip = "127.0.0.1" }
val pnTest = PNCounter()(TestConfig)
pnTest.ownIP // "127.0.0.1"   (OK)
pnTest.p.ownIP     // "192.168.0.1" (NOT OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an argument *is* the right way to do it (that's essentially what "dependency injection" means).

You can make the argument implicit (and/or give it a default value) to preserve the (appearance of) the interface:

```
trait Config { def ip: String }
object Config extends Config { val ip = "127.0.0.1" }

case class Number(value: Int)(implicit config: Config = Config) {
   def getIp = config.ip
}

describe("Number") {
   it("uses IP from given config") {
     implicit val config = mock[Config] 
     when(config.ip).thenReturn("foo") 
     Number(123).ip shouldBe "foo"
     verify(config).ip
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i’ll take a look at it first thing tomorrow morning!

Comment: At first glance it does not change the appearance of the interface, but once you start defining more complex replicated data types it does change the interface (see update).

Comment: @Kevin yes, the more complex the data types, the more complex the interfaces. That's the fact of life. A good rule is to think about testability as you _design_ the interfaces to your complex types. Then you won't have to test them when it comes to testing.
FWIW, the last snippet in your update doesn't make any sense, I don't know how you ended up with three argument lists, and can't begin to imagine what purpose that `nestedNum` can possibly serve. In a nutshell, you just need to add `(implicit config: Config)` everywhere.

Comment: Well, it does make sense to nest replicated data types. For instance, in the literature on conflict-free replicated data types (CRDTs) a PN-Counter consists of two G-Counters. So we could define it as: `case class PNCounter(val p: GCounter = GCounter(), val n: GCounter = GCounter())`. Also, making the argument implicit everywhere does not work with nested objects (see what I mean in update 2 of my post).

Comment: It does work with nested objects. You just showed how in your second update.

Comment: It doesn't, when accessing the IP address from within the nested object it returns the wrong one: `pnTest.p // "192.168.0.1" (NOT OK)` this is **not** the IP address from the test config.

Comment: So, you implemented it wrong. You want the _same_ implicit config everywhere.
Just declare the mock as implicit in your test (I updated the answer to show how)

Comment: Besides, when testing, the nested objects should be the ones mocked, not (just) the config.